# TurboC++ graphics.h conflict with conio.h's clreol()

Tags: c, conflict, turbo-c++, bgi

*Note: This is TurboC++ so please don't expect STL*

I have this simple code that have no other `graphics.h` functions rather than it's driver's declaration and call. I aim to:

- Print a first string *(A longer one)*
- Go to the first string's coordinates, clear that string *(using* `clreol()`*)*
- Print the second string which is shorter.

But I rather get this output on print of second string:

```
Shorter phrase.██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████
```

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <graphics.h>

int gdriver=DETECT, gmode;

void main(){
    clrscr();
    initgraph(&gdriver,&gmode,"C:\\TURBOC3\\BGI");

    printf("Longer phrase than next.");
    getch();
    gotoxy(1,1);
    clreol();
    printf("Shorter phrase.");
    getch();
}
```

When I remove the `initgraph()` function, it works fine, so there might be the problem, but of course I need it.

Comment: The 1990's just called.  They want their compiler back!

Comment: Suspect code needs to set the foreground and background colors.

Comment: it's better let DOS rest in peace, except in some situations

Comment: @chux I suspect if I change that excessive thing to black, it would change also my text color

Answer (score 1):

Haha - coding problems from stoneage ;). Thanks for this - it activated some nice memories.

My guess would be that you run into problems because you are mixing BGI (graphics) functions and "normal" text output. Try replacing the text output calls with calls to the corresponding BGI functions (if I remember correctly, this was called outtextxy() or something).

Comment: Also the graphics initialization looks too plain, I think you needed more code than that to get BGI going. And I believe there was also some clean-up function call.